# Выделение подлежащего

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения

Предположим, есть предложение: "Все остальные, так или иначе, относятся к нему".
Как тут правильно выделить подлежащее?

Answer (score 1):

**"Все остальные"** - подлежащее. Выделять из него составляющие как отдельные члены предложения в данной фразе смысла не вижу. Но это уже другой разговор.

"Относятся" - сказуемое.

Собственно, тут и предмета для широкого обсуждения я не вижу. Может, вы разъясните, в чем было ваше затруднение.

Answer (score 0):

***Все остальные, так или иначе, относятся к нему.***

Контекста нет, и скорее не предвидится.

Но если это двусоставное предложение, то в нем должно быть подлежащее.
По структуре на эту роль подходит субстантивированное прилагательное ***остальные***, местоимение ***все*** в роли определения.

Приведу свой пример: ***Этот вопрос является главным, все остальные (вопросы), так или иначе, относятся к немУ.***

Как мы видим, здесь имеет место **временная субстантивация** прилагательного (при отсутствии пропущенного существительного).

Можно сказать: *остальные вопросы*, то есть опустить местоимение *все*. Поэтому я посчитала его определением.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) Никак не могу понять, что там неверно **с контекстом.**

**Контекст здесь нужен,** так как  предложение неполное, с  пропущенным подлежащим, которое восстанавливается из предыдущего текста. Поэтому приходится придумывать свой вариант, чтобы объяснить, почему прилагательное становится подлежащим. **Контекст нужен не всегда,** но в некоторых случаях он просто необходим.

Из словаря: **ПРЕДВИДЕТЬСЯ,** -дится; нсв. Ожидаться, предполагаться. Предвидится жаркий день. Уже предвиделась неизбежность конфликта. **Изменений не предвидится.**

Вот и контекста не предвидится (не ожидается).

2) И зачем обособлять ***скорее***, здесь это наречие со значением ***скорее не предвидится, чем предвидится***.

Вот правило: http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_671

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99077/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--).

Comment: Тогда "скорее" тоже вводное, но без обособления (следуя gramota.ru). В таком случае перед "скорее" должен быть глагол, а после - существительное. Но главное, что тогда "скорее" используется в значении "больше" (взаимозаменяемо). Ваш пример не подходит. Уверен, что запятые нужны.

Comment: Ставьте, если уверены, я же уверена в обратном.  И глагол никому и ничего не должен, порядок слов в русском языке  условно свободный и может меняться в зависимости от структуры предложения и расстановки ударений.

Comment: Читать умеете. Цитирую свой ответ: скорее не предвидится, чем предвидится.  Что же еще-то объяснять???  И Грамоту почитайте. Там вводное слово скорее обозначает скорее говоря. У меня нет этого значения.

Comment: Но ведь во всех примерах при сопоставлении "скорее" используется в значении "больше". Более того, тогда "скорее" нельзя заменить на "вернее" или "точнее сказать", но не в вашем примере. Такой смысл возможен и при глаголах: *скорее не согласен - больше не согласен*.  Ваш же пример выходит из общего строя. Заменяем: *Больше не предвидится, чем предвидится* - подходит. Но: *Контекста нет, и больше не предвидится* - ерунда.

Comment: Извините, но я не вижу смысла в нашем разговоре. Я уже сказала: ставьте свои запятые, как вам нравится.  Или задайте на форуме вопрос про это предложение,  если вам это очень интересно.